# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'StringVar'

Tags: python, tkinter

why i am not able to add these two. while receving from Entry.kindly help me

```
utility_var=StringVar()
buildingrent_var=StringVar()
total_var=StringVar()

utility_institute=Label(reg_frame,text="UTILITY",bg='grey',fg='white',font=("times new 
roman",15,'bold'))
utility_institute.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=10,sticky='w')
utility_institute_entry=Entry(reg_frame,textvariable=utility_var,font=("",12,'bold'))
utility_institute_entry.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)

buildingrent=Label(reg_frame,text="BUILDING RENT",bg='grey',fg='white',font=("times new 
roman",15,'bold'))
buildingrent.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=10,sticky='w')
buildingrent_entry=Entry(reg_frame,textvariable=buildingrent_var,font=("",12,'bold'))
buildingrent_entry.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=5,pady=5)               

 def add():
            total_var=int(utility_var)+int(buildingrent_var)
            print(total_var)
```

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** What do you understand from that error, and have you done any debugging?

Comment: Read up on [The Variable Classes - Methods `get/set`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) how to `.get()` and `.set()` a value.

Comment: File "c:\Users\Mr.HAZIQ\Desktop\My Work\Python\Project\Schooling Project.py", line 67, in add
    total_var=int(utility_var)+int(buildingrent_var)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'StringVar'
Exception in Tkinter callback

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you have is that you are trying to add two empty stringvars.

to set a stringvar:

```
from tkinter import *
a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()

a.set('hi do you understand now')
b.set('By the way, you can\'t add StringVars...')
```

You can't add StringVars but you can set stringvars with variables
example:

```
from tkinter import *
a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
ranvar1 = 'hi do you understand now'
ranvar2 = 'By the way, you can\'t add StringVars...'

a.set(ranvar1)
b.set(ranvar2)
```

with this in mind, you can add ranvar1 and ranvar2:

```
from tkinter import *
a = StringVar()
b = StringVar()
ranvar1 = 'hi do you understand now'
ranvar2 = 'By the way, you can\'t add StringVars...'

a.set(ranvar1)
b.set(ranvar2)

ranvar1 + ranvar2 = ranvar3
TotalVar = ranvar3
```

Comment: i am giving the value of those two variables through my entry but still having problem

Comment: File "c:\Users\Mr.HAZIQ\Desktop\My Work\Python\Project\Schooling Project.py", line 67, in add
    total_var=int(utility_var)+int(buildingrent_var)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'StringVar'
Exception in Tkinter callback

Comment: @ManahilAsfand you can't int(StringVar) you have to int a variable then set the variable to the stringvar